# How to make a Mat Fab Extended Flat Button in Angulat Material without custom rules?

Tags: angular-material

Angular material has many different buttons options: https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples.
I'm currently trying to use an extended fab button (taller and with large border radius when compared to the Flat button). However, I don't want to have shadow in the button.
I was wandering if there are rules available within Angular Material to make this work without relying on custom rules?

Angular material:
[image: original]
Goal:
[image: goal]

I tried to combine flat with the directives `mat-fab`, `extended` and `flat`, or `mat-flat-button` and `extended` without success.